# Adding formula to all existing formulas in an Excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm setting up a monthly call tracker for sales and customer service. I have almost everything built out, but I'm looking to add the IFERROR function to all cells in the sheet that have a formula in them. Is there a blanket way to do this or do I have to do it one at a time. Below is an example of the different formulas I'm working with.

```
=COUNTIFS('JAN DATA'!H:H,"Commercial",'JAN DATA'!I:I,"New Sales")

=SUM(SUMIFS('JAN DATA'!G:G,'JAN DATA'!H:H,"Commercial",'JAN DATA'!I:I,"New Sales"),SUMIFS('JAN DATA'!G:G,'JAN DATA'!H:H,"Commercial",'JAN DATA'!I:I,"Inspection"))/(E4+E5),"")
```

I have 15 people I'm tracking and about 5 lines of unique code per person every month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article
[How to bulk insert IFERROR to existing Excel formulas!](https://professor-excel.com/how-to-bulk-insert-iferror-to-existing-excel-formulas/)
explains that if you don't want to do update each formula,
perhaps using copy-paste for the `IFERROR(` part, you need to
use a VBA macro.

The proposed macro is :

```
Sub insertIFERRORtoCells()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim result As String
    result = InputBox("What text should be displayed in case of an error?", "Insert IFERROR function: Error Text")
    If StrPtr(result) <> 0 Then
        For Each cell In Selection.Cells
            On Error Resume Next
            If cell.HasFormula Then
                cell.Formula = "=IFERROR(" & Right(cell.Formula, Len(cell.Formula) - 1) & "," & result & ")"
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

The article adds these notes :

> The VBA macro above solves its purpose. Nevertheless, it comes with
> some disadvantages:
>
> - All formulas must start with the = sign. Formulas starting with `=-` or `=+` might lead to errors.
> - If your existing formula already has an IFERROR function, it won’t be replaced but an additional IFERROR function is added around.
> - Of course, it comes with all the other disadvantages of VBA macros (for example, it’s just locally available, difficult to maintain,
>   etc.)
>
> So, please test this VBA macro carefully and better save a backup of
> your file before you use it!